# If $f$ is continuous, then $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int^b_a n(f(x+ 1/n)-f(x)) \lambda(dx) = f(b)-f(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Consider a continuous function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and define $f_n: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by $f_n(x) = n(f(x+1/n)-f(x))$.

I want to show that for $a < b \in \mathbb R$ we have $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int^b_a f_n(x) \lambda(dx) = f(b)-f(a),$$ where $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure.

I've tried to use dominated convergence, but it didn't work. Evaluating the integral I get $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int^b_a f_n(x) \lambda(dx) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\int^b_a f(x+1/n) dx - n\int^b_a f(x) dx,$$ and I can't really continue from here.

Comment: $f_n(x) \to f^\prime (x)$ pointwise.

Comment: Suggestion: Consider transforming the first integral on the right hand side by $x\mapsto x-1/n$.

Comment: @MustafaSaid $f$ is not assumed differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, for every $n$, $$\int^b_a f_n(x) \lambda(dx)=n\int^{b+1/n}_b f(x) \lambda(dx)-n\int^{a+1/n}_a f(x) \lambda(dx).$$ Can you identify the limit of each term on the RHS? Hint: only the continuity of $f$ is needed.

Comment: Have you made the transformation suggested above to get this equality ? And do you use the fact that the Riemann integral is continuous ? On the right side, I get a limit on the form $\infty  \cdot (f(b)-f(a))$ ?

Comment: Also, how do you get your integral boundaries ?

Comment: "Have you made the transformation suggested above to get this equality ?" Which transformation? "And do you use the fact that the Riemann integral is continuous ?" Nope. "On the right side, I get a limit on the form ∞⋅(f(b)−f(a)) ?" This is not the limit. How did you get that? As I said, *only the continuity of $f$* (at $a$ and at $b$) is involved.

Comment: I get that limit, since we I let $n \rightarrow \infty$ on R.H.S, both scalars ($n$) approach $\infty$.

Comment: Sure---but $n$ is multiplied by an integral$$\int_{c}^{c+1/n}f(x)\lambda(dx),$$ for $c=b$ or for $c=a$, hence if these integrals converge to $0$ (and they do), the limit $\infty\times0$ is indeterminate. As a first step, can you show that each of these integrals converges to $0$?

Comment: I will try, thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've not yet the required skills to proceed.

Comment: This is almost surely not true. You know that $f$ is continuous, in particular, on the interval $[c,c+1]$, $|f|$ is $______$, hence ...

Comment: I see that $|f| = f^+ + f^-$ must also be continuous, since it is the composition of two continuous functions. But how is this supposed to help that $|f|$ is continuous ?

Comment: It helps because then $|f|$ is b-----d.

Comment: Aha, so we get $$n ((b + 1/n) - b) K  = K$$ for the first integral ?

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. What is this new "K"?